# Expression templates not working for primitive type overloads under clang

Tags: c++, c++11, expression-templates

I have a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) base class as follows:

```
template<typename Derived, size_t DIMS>
class Base {
public:
    // here is I think where the problem is
    inline const Derived& self() const {return *static_cast<const Derived*>(this);}
};
```

Then the derived class is defined as

```
template<typename T, size_t ... Rest>
class Derived: public Base<Derived<T,Rest...>,sizeof...(Rest)> {
public:

    Derived() = default;

    // This constructor binds any arbitrary expression to Derived
    template<typename Expr, size_t DIMS>
    inline Derived(const Base<Expr,DIMS>& src_) {
        const Expr &src = src_.self();
        print(src.rhs);
    }
};
```

with defining my own operators in mind, I also have the following `AddOperator` which also inherits from base

```
template<typename TLhs, typename TRhs, size_t DIMS>
struct AddOperator: public Base<AddOperator<TLhs, TRhs, DIMS>,DIMS> {
    AddOperator(const TLhs& lhs, const TRhs& rhs) : lhs(lhs), rhs(rhs) {
        print(rhs);
    }
    const TLhs &lhs;
    const TRhs &rhs;
};
```

Then the `operator+` overload between a `Derived` type and a primitive type returns only a proxy/expression of sorts:

```
template<typename TLhs, typename TRhs, size_t DIM0,
         typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<TLhs>::value &&
                                 std::is_arithmetic<TRhs>::value,bool>::type = 0 >
inline AddOperator<TLhs, TRhs, DIM0> 
operator+(const Base<TLhs,DIM0> &lhs, TRhs rhs) {
  return AddOperator<TLhs, TRhs, DIM0>(lhs.self(), rhs);
}
```

However, when I call this under `clang` I get garbage values for `rhs` of `AddOperator`. Here is an example:

```
int main() {

    Derived<double,2,2> g;
    Derived<double,2,2> x = g+28;

    return 0;
}
```

The other overloads when both `lhs` and `rhs` in `AddOperator` are of type `Derived` do not have this problem.

This problem happens only under `clang`. `gcc` compiled code seems to run fine. Does anyone know where the problem is?

[Full Demo Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ef08915bb306cdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a dangling reference.

In `operator+`, you take a `TRhs` (`int`) by value and then construct an `AddOperator<...>` with a reference to it. When `g+28` returns, the `AddOperator<...>` object still has a reference to the parameter `rhs` - whose lifetime has now ended.

The garbage you're printing is the outcome of accessing a destroyed object - it's undefined behavior. On clang, this manifests itself as printing a garbage value for you, on gcc it happens to work. Undefined behavior is tricky like that.

---

Now, the seemingly "obvious" fix is to change `operator+` to take `rhs` by reference to `const`. This will extend the lifetime of the temporary `28` through the end of the full expression containing the call - so now your print statements are guaranteed to work. At least, until the end of the line. After `x` is constructed, the reference will dangle yet again.

Comment: I noticed it myself as soon as I posted the question. Thanks